# Detect and open a Postal Address in Swift(iOS) using NSDataDetector

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatadetector

I currently have a UITextView with Address detection active, this detects any addresses in this field and makes them into a clickable link that opens up Apple Maps with the address as the focus. I really like this functionality but my users would rather have a button to click on instead of the inline link.
With this in mind I have researched into NSDataDetector and managed to get this functionality working for emailing and phone numbers but I am stuck on Addresses. The code I am using to detect the address is below:

```
    let types: NSTextCheckingType = [.Address]
    let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
    let matches = detector.matchesInString(input, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count))
    for match in matches {
        return NSURL(string: "\((input as NSString).substringWithRange(match.range))")
    }
```

However the NSURL fails to be created, I believe the syntax must be wrong, it works for phone numbers as below:

```
    let types: NSTextCheckingType = [.PhoneNumber]
    let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
    let matches = detector.matchesInString(input, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count))
    for match in matches {
        return NSURL(string: "telprompt://\((input as NSString).substringWithRange(match.range))")
    }
```

If the address is valid it returns the components of the address(street, city etc.) in the matches object. I was hoping the NSURL could be used with address just like phone numbers but I may be wrong so is there an alternate way I could use the results from the detector and display them on Apple Maps manually?

Or as a side note could I hide the UITextView and trigger the link touch programatically based on a button touch?

Any more information can be provided as needed, 
thank you in advance for any help.